# Help number pages

Tags: number, pagestyle

[image]
I want the first part to be numbered in Roman numerals. And the second part in regular numbers.And the numbering continues in every chapter.

Comment: Please make your question more clear. What is "the first example" of desired numbering that you refer to? We can see only one picture, is it the problem or the solution that you are looking for?

Comment: Do you want to replace the Roman numerals (I, II, III, IV, ....) by the Arabic (1, 2, 3, ...) or do you want to make the page numbering continuous from the beginning at Resume (page 1) until the end (for example introduction be page 12, chapter 1 be page 15 and so on)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which document class do you employ?

Comment: Note that lower case roman is the default for frontmatter in book class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have been a great help if you had provided an MWE (from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`) that showed your problem and that we could process in order to help you.

It is unclear to me just what you want but the following is an MWE that may, or may not, help you and which shows changing page number representations.

```
% pagenumberprob.tex SE 559546
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{Roman} % use Roman page numbers, starting from I
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Abstract}
\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic} % use arabic page numbers starting from 1
\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Problem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am using  document class  article.

Comment: @Aicha In that case use `\section` instead of `\chapter` and don't use `\frontmatter` or `\mainmatter`.